# Why only a specific pressure for the Haber's process?

Tags: equilibrium, kinetics

This question, in my opinion is different from [Why is the Haber process carried out at such high temperatures?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/43356/14806)

Referring to the above link, I understand that why high temperature of 700 K is chosen, i.e, to overcome the activation energy barrier as well as kinetic considerations. However, why is the pressure 200 atm only. Why not 300?

According to Le Chatelier's principle, there larger the pressure, more ammonia will be formed.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question. I would like a better verified answer, but for now I can direct you to a quote from the Wikipedia page for the [Haber Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haber_process#Reaction_rate_and_equilibrium): "Economically, pressure is an expensive commodity. Pipes and reaction vessels need to be strengthened, valves more rigorous, and there are safety considerations of working at 20 MPa. In addition, running pumps and compressors takes considerable energy. Thus the compromise used gives a single pass yield of around 15%."(The claim doesn't have a citation)